# Get all documents from a Firebase collection and set to static var Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

How to get all documents from firebase and set it to static var?

example

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final officeRef = firestore.collection("office");

class CompanyData {

  ***static Map<String, dynamic> /id/ = {
  };***
}
```

from firebase like this
[FirebaseDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Byx.png)

How i can get result like this(***) so i can use it for another page..

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class CompanyData {

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

final officeRef = firestore.collection("office");

***
  static Map<String, dynamic> office1 = {
    'name': "OFFICE 1ST",
    'code': "c_office1",
    'latitude': -4.001,
    'longitude': 100.001,
  };
  static Map<String, dynamic> office2 = {
    'name': "OFFICE 2ND",
    'code': "c_office2",
    'latitude': -4.002,
    'longitude': 100.002,
  };
  static Map<String, dynamic> office3 = {
    'name': "OFFICE 3RD",
    'code': "c_office3",
    'latitude': -4.003,
    'longitude': 100.003,
  };
  static Map<String, dynamic> etc.....
}
***
```

I'm sorry,
I still very new to flutter and firebase.. so still many things i dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

Create new file `static_variable.dart`
Create StaticVariable class like this:

```
class StaticVariable {
  static bool? navigateRedeem;
  static String? keywordJob;
  static User? myUser;
}
```

Request api when open app, you can request api in SplashScreen or everywhere you want, it up to you,

After data response, set new data for StaticVariable:

```
//request api here: var res = await request .....
StaticVariable.myUser = res['user]
```

Then, you can call StaticVariable in everywhere in your project

Example:

**static.dart**

```
class StaticVariable {
  static String? textHello;
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:demo/static.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'home.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    StaticVariable.textHello = 'Hihihi';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: HomeScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:demo/static.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(StaticVariable.textHello ?? ''),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Similar with request api

Comment: thank you, but most my problem are after i call data from firestore and set ` StaticVariable.myUser = data['user]`, how to send it to a class(controller) at another page/dart?,i always get null value / error not defined. are the only way using state widget?

Comment: i'm sorry, because i from web dev so i too used to with MVC, so i want store data firestore at model and controller can call it when i need.. 
well eventough right now i'm just using firebase query in everypage in need..

Comment: use any state management, It is necessary too